# When I call my php script in another, Select js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code which works fine when ran standalone (I am able to search in the drop down list )

```
<?php

include_once ("db_connection.php");

$conn = testdb_connect ();

$sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT testCase FROM tooldata ');

$sth->execute();

    while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        { 
        foreach($row as $key) 
            {
                $var=explode('_', $key);
                $feature[] =  $var[0];  
            } 
        }
$feature = array_intersect_key($feature, array_unique(array_map('strtolower', $feature)));
    foreach($feature as $newarr) 
        {
            $newFeature[]=$newarr;
        }
?>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../select2-3.4.8/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="../select2-3.4.8/select2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { $("#feature").select2(); });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Select feature</h2>
<form method="get" action="feature.php">
<select name="feature" id="feature">
        <?php
        ?>
        <option value > Select Feature</option>
        <?php
        foreach($newFeature as $feat)
        {
            ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $feat;?>"><?php echo $feat;?></option>
            <?php
       }
         ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Feature">
</body>
</html>
```

When I include this script in other php script say main.php and when I run main.php my search in the drop down list does not work and I get this in my net tab - **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  for line 7 and 37** which are **include("feature_list.php");** and **}** respectively.

what can be the possible reason for this ?
please guide

Comment: Did you try to include it in an empty php file?

Comment: @Daan - yes and it didnt work

Comment: Line numbers in the Javascript console refer to the HTML source received, not the original PHP. The `include` line shouldn't be in the  document in the browser.

Comment: The script is being interpreted as JS? Try setting a header as HTML on top, say `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` maybe?

Comment: The new php file is in the same folder?

Comment: @R3tep yes all are in the same folder

Comment: You're not closing your FORM tag.